# Added icon in UILabel background, next want to change icon tint colour

Tags: ios, swift

I have added icon in UILabel background, next I want to change icon tint colour, but the color is not changing at all because I do not know what code I have to write for it. UILabel data comes from web. I added icon after loading data

**Extension**

```
    extension UILabel {

        func addImageWith(name: String, behindText: Bool) {

            let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
            attachment.image = UIImage(named: name)
            let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

            guard let txt = self.text else {
                return
            }

            if behindText {
                let strLabelText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: txt)
                strLabelText.append(attachmentString)
                self.attributedText = strLabelText
            } else {
                let strLabelText = NSAttributedString(string: txt)
                let mutableAttachmentString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attachmentString)
                mutableAttachmentString.append(strLabelText)
                self.attributedText = mutableAttachmentString
            }
        }

        func removeImage() {
            let text = self.text
            self.attributedText = nil
            self.text = text
        }
    }

   //Label

      let addressLabel: UILabel = {

            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = " COMIC CAFE, BANNAI"
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 6)
            label.textColor = .orange

            label.addImageWith(name: "location copy", behindText: false)

            label.textAlignment = .center

            return label
               }()

    **didSet in cell** 
        didSet {

                if let address = product?.store_address {

                    addressLabel.text = product?.store_address
                    addressLabel.addImageWith(name: "location", behindText: false)
                }else {
                    addressLabel.text = ""
                }
```

Comment: "next I want to change image tint colour, but the color is not changing at all" Where is that part of the code?

Comment: addressLabel.addImageWith(name: "location", behindText: false)

Comment: @Larme added Icon in UILabel backGround, now want to change icon tint colour

Comment: @Larme check again my code because change in it

Comment: "now want to change icon tint colour" That's what I'm afraid about your definition of chaning the icon tintColor. You mean that for instance if you have a red circle with a white star in it, the image will be a other color circle with a white start in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you cannot do it.

```
let label = UILabel()

label.text = " COMIC CAFE, BANNAI"
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 6)
label.textColor = .orange

label.addImageWith(name: "location copy", behindText: false)
label.textAlignment = .center`
```